# Degree of Toric Divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry

Is it possible to calculate the degree of a toric divisor directly from the fan of the toric
variety?
If so, how is this done? Or is there some alternative way to calculate the degree of these divisors?

Comment: The set of Cartier T-divisors on a fan is exactly the set of piecewise linear integral functions on the fan. Given such a function, one can recover the divisor by finding the values of the function at the first lattice elements which are the coefficients of the irreducible divisors associated to rays ( 1- dimensional cones)

Answer (score 3):

Let the toric variety be $X$; let $d = \mathrm{dim} \ X$. For any Cartier $T$-divisor $D$, we can describe $\dim H^0(X, \mathcal{O}(D))$ as the number of lattice points in a certain polytope $P_D$. See Section 5.3 of Fulton's *Introduction to Toric Varieties*. The degree of $D$ is $d! \mathrm{Vol}(P_D)$.

Proof: Let $h(n)$ be the Hilbert polynomial $h(n) = \dim H^0(X, \mathcal{O}(nD))$. We know that the leading term of $h(n)$ is $\mathrm{deg}(\mathcal{O}(D)) n^d/d!$. But also, the number of lattice points in $n \cdot P_D$ is $\mathrm{Vol}(P_D) n^d + O(n^{d-1})$. Equating these two, $\mathrm{deg}(\mathcal{O}(D)) = d! \mathrm{Vol}(P_D)$. $\square$

Comment: I'm curious, wouldn't this imply that $\mathrm{deg}(\mathcal{O}(D))=D^d$ according to Fulton's book (p. 111)? (This lead to my own question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174656/degree-of-a-divisor-self-intersection)